# Como posso imprimir uma string em vez de char?

Tags: c

No código a seguir tenho um char com 2 caracteres, `H` (`Heads`) e `T` (`Tails`), na hora da impressão claramente será impresso uma dessas 2 letras, mas eu queria fazer uma mudança e imprimir "Cara" ou "Coroa". De que maneira eu teria que fazer isso? Através de um vetor de string? Se sim como?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char fc[2] = {'H','T'};
    srand(time(NULL));

    int i =0;
    int j = 0;
    char temp ;
    int c;
    printf("Nesse programa voce pode ver quantas vezes seria preciso para uma moeda cair X vezes do mesmo lado.\n");
    printf("Digite quantas vezes em sequencia a moeda deve cair:\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);

    while(i < c){
        char comp = fc[rand()%2];
        if (j == 0){
            printf("inicio\n");
            temp = comp;            
        }
        else if(temp == comp){
            i++;
            temp = comp;
            printf("%c\n", comp);
        }
        else {
            i = 0;
            printf("%c\n", comp);
        }
        j++;
    }

    printf("Tentativas: %d\n", j-1);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Já tentei fazer as seguintes alterações na declaração e nas impressões:

```
 char fc[2][10] = {"Cara", "Coroa"};
 printf("%s" , comp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você declara uma *array* de ponteiros para *strings*:

```
char * fc[2] = { "Cara", "Coroa" };
```

Em seguida, soteia-se um dos ponteiros contidos na *array*:

```
char * comp = fc[ rand() % 2 ];
```

Para exibir a *string* a partir do ponteiro sorteado:

```
printf( "%s" ,comp );
```

Colocando tudo junto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main( void )
{
    char * fc[2] = { "Cara","Coroa" };
    int x = 0;
    int nmax = 0;
    int aux = -1;
    int ntentativas = 0;
    int nrepeticoes = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Nesse programa voce pode ver quantas vezes seria preciso para uma moeda cair X vezes do mesmo lado.\n");
    printf("Digite quantas vezes em sequencia a moeda deve cair:\n");
    scanf( "%d", &nmax );

    while( nrepeticoes < nmax )
    {
        ntentativas++;

        x = rand() % 2;

        printf( "Tentativa %d: %s\n", ntentativas, fc[x] );

        if( aux == x )
            nrepeticoes++;
        else
            nrepeticoes = 1;

        aux = x;
    }

    printf("Numero de Tentativas: %d\n", ntentativas );

    return 0;
}
```

Testando:

```
$ ./moeda
Nesse programa voce pode ver quantas vezes seria preciso para uma moeda cair X vezes do mesmo lado.
Digite quantas vezes em sequencia a moeda deve cair:
4
Tentativa 1: Cara
Tentativa 2: Cara
Tentativa 3: Coroa
Tentativa 4: Coroa
Tentativa 5: Cara
Tentativa 6: Coroa
Tentativa 7: Cara
Tentativa 8: Cara
Tentativa 9: Cara
Tentativa 10: Cara
Numero de Tentativas: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char fc[2][10] = {"Cara", "Coroa"};
```

Repare que o seu array tem:

posição 0: ['C','a','r','a','',...]

posição 1: ['C','o','r','o','a','',...]

enquanto `comp` for um char,

```
char comp = fc[rand()%2];
```

esta função não vai executar. `comp = ['C','a','r','a','',...];` falha visto que `comp` é um único `char`.

Adicionalmente, `rand()` tem de ser inicializado. O resultado de `rand()` chamado assim vai ser sempre 0. [Fonte](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm)

```
srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
//em alternativa: 
// time_t t;
// srand((unsigned) time(&t));
```

Aqui está a solução:

```
int main() 
{
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    char fc[2][10] = {"Cara", "Coroa"};
    char *comp = fc[rand()%2];
    printf("%s" , comp);
}
```

Comment: Somente `srand((unsigned)time(NULL));` seria suficiente para inicializar o gerador de números pseudo aleatórios a partir da hora do sistema. [A função `time()` suporta parametro nulo](https://linux.die.net/man/2/time).

Comment: Editado, obrigado.